# Can quasarExcludePackages be used within the deployNodes gradle task?

Tags: corda

I've tried using this with the following constants:

```
cordaReleaseGroup=net.corda
cordaCoreReleaseGroup=net.corda
cordaVersion=4.5.1
cordaCoreVersion=4.5.1
gradlePluginsVersion=5.0.9
kotlinVersion=1.2.71
junitVersion=4.12
quasarVersion=0.7.10
log4jVersion=2.11.2
platformVersion=5
slf4jVersion=1.7.25
```

... with the following `deployNodes`

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
   nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }
        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
        quasarExcludePackages = ["io.cordite.braid.libs**"]
    }
```

Gradle throws an error for `unknown property` for `quasarExcludePackages`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it via extra config like so:

```
nodeDefaults {
    projectCordapp {
        deploy = false
    }
    cordapp project(':contracts')
    cordapp project(':workflows')
    extraConfig = ["quasarExcludePackages": ["io.cordite.braid.libs**"]]
}
```